# My browser doesn't interprete my css files

Tags: html, css, browser, server

I just started a very simple exercise and I created a simple html file and a css file (inside css folder), in order to learn more about Angularjs.
The exercise starts by creating these 2 files (so no Angularjs yet).

For some reason the css file is not rendered in any of my browsers.
On Chrome, I inspected the index.html file, and click on resources and the Css file is there! but its not working.

I don't know what to do, but it seems a very stupid error.
I've read in a couple of places that it maybe related to a file called nginx.conf

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
     <body>
       <div id="myQuizz">


      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css/style.css

```
body { background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; }

#myQuiz {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;
 width: 650px; height: 650px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #fff;
 background: #000 url(.../images/background.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

#myQuiz h2 {font-size: 3em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100;} 
#myQuiz h3 {font-size: 2.4em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100;}
#myQuiz p { margin: 0px 0px 14px 0px; }
#myQuiz .btn{
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #c04b01;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
/* Intro */
#myQuiz  .intro { position: absolute; top: 225px; left: 40px; width: 550px;}
#myQuiz .intro p { margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px; }
```

Comment: Your HTML has no content (empty div) so what are you expecting to see?

Comment: It looks to be setting a height and width along with a background color so you should be seeing at least the color, unless it's off the viewable area. I'd try changing the inline-block to just block to see if you get the expected result.

Comment: There is a typo: `myQuizz` vs. `myQuiz`

Comment: Bro, check the spelling of `myQuizz` in your html and `myQuiz` in css

Comment: Your HTML is empty, of course you are not seeing anything! Try changing the `body` rule to this `body { background-color: red; padding: 20px; }` and if it is red, your CSS is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people noticed, you misspelled your id inline your HTML div tag. So change id="myQuizz" to id="myQuiz".

```
<div id="myQuiz"></div>
```

I created a fiddle, It corrects the myQuiz typo, and adds a generic background so you can see it. I also added

```
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
```

Just so you can see the background

http://jsfiddle.net/hb7du2xq/

Answer (score 0):

Other than checking your link path to your stylesheet(css must be in a folder called 'css'), I agree with Wesley, you must put content inside your div to be able to see anything. Such as:

```
<p>Hello World.</p>
```

Copy and paste that inside this:

```
<div id="myQuizz">

</div>
```

So that it looks like this:

```
<div id="myQuizz">
    <p>Hello World.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Terrible-not picking up my html tags. <div id="myQuizz"><p></p></div>

Answer (score 0):

buddy, either remove one "z" from id="myQuizz" ... or add one more "z" to your css selectors like #myQuizz .... browser is not interpreting the stles because it isn't able to find one. :)

Answer (score 0):

After some time,I managed to get your error and it has nothing to do with the css file or your browser. It's just a typo in your code.

Just change the id of your `div` from `<div id="myQuizz">` to `<div id="myQuiz">`.This is because you used `#myQuiz{.....}` in your css